# When I run the code, why does it leave a big gap in the transition to the second shape after the first shape is created?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void square(int s,char shape)
{
  printf("%c",shape);
}

int main( void )
{
  int side;
  char shape;   

  while(side>=0)
  {
    printf("Enter the character you want: ");
    scanf("%c",&shape);
    
    printf("Input the size of side: ");
    /* How can I prevent gaps when I run the console as shown in the picture */
    
    if(side<0)
    {
      break;
    }
    
    scanf("%d",&side);

    for(int i=1;i<=side;i++)
    {
      for(int j=1;j<=side;j++)
      {
        square(side,shape); 
      }
      puts("");
    }
  }
  getch();  
}
```

[image]

Comment: `int side; while(side>=0) .. if(side<0)..` There are several places where `side` is used before it is set to any value. That's Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

- you use the value of *side* before to read/set it, to use a non initialized value has an undefined behavior. You must read *side* before to use it.
- you mix reading of integer and character, when you read an integer all the characters after the integer and *not* read nor flush, so when after you read a character you read the first non read character, for instance the newline enter after the integer. You must flush the spaces when you read the character, for that you just need to put a space before `%c` so `scanf(" %c",&shape);`
- you never check if *scanf* success, then you do not check the user enter a valid integer when you read the size, nor even if the end of file was reach when you read the character or the integer. You must check that
- you define the function *square* getting two arguments but using only one, and the name of the function does not correspond to its behavior. You can remove that function just printing a char, or have that function drawing a square
- to use *printf* and *puts* to just print a character this is an expensive way, use *putchar*
- to use *printf* to print a string as it is is also expensive for nothing, use *puts* of *fputs* to not have the final newline

A way to do can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void square(int side, int shape)
{
  for (int line = 1; line <= side; ++line)
  {
    for (int column = 1; column <= side; ++column)
    {
      putchar(shape);
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
}


int main( void )
{
  for (;;)
  {
    int side;
    char shape;   
    
    fputs("Enter the character you want: ", stdout);
    if (scanf(" %c",&shape) != 1) 
    {
      /* EOF */
      break;
    }
    
    fputs("Input the size of side: ", stdout);
    if ((scanf("%d", &side) != 1) || /* not a valid integer or EOF */
        (side <= 0)) /* not a valid size */
    {
      break;
    }
    
    square(side, shape);
  }

  // getch() if you want, typically for Windows
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter the character you want: $
Input the size of side: 3
$$$
$$$
$$$
Enter the character you want: %
Input the size of side: 1
%
Enter the character you want: *
Input the size of side: aze
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```